# how to limited input number limit to 100

Tags: javascript, html

I want to limited my input value to 100 only the number entered it should be 0 to 100 and it shouldn't go more then 100 how can I do this

This is The input code

```
    Enter Html Marks.........
    <input  id="hm"  type="tel" size="4" maxlength="3" />
```

My friend told me about unicode but I don't know anything about unicode
please explain about unicode too

Comment: Tell your friend to stop messing with you. It has nothing to do with unicode, and it's impossible with pure HTML. You need to use JS validation for this.

Comment: @Amit `maxlength` has something to do with unicode, and what the OP wants to do is possible with HTML5

Comment: @Kaiido can you explain - How does maxlength and unicode relate? (And yes, you're right about HTML5)

Comment: @Amit well maxLength="x" allows x unicode code points. so if you take a combining character like backtick ` you can actually enter x+1 of them but  if you take some composed one like U+E01A5, you will be able to enter only x/2 of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) method.

```
<input id="hm" type="tel" size="4" maxlength="3" onchange="changeHandler(this)"/>
```

In that changeHandler function you check the value of your input and set it back to 100 if it was higher:

```
<script>
  function changeHandler(val)
  {
    if (Number(val.value) > 100)
    {
      val.value = 100
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Pattern Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp). and put this [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) inside "\b(0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100))\b"

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with  unicode, you can do this by using javascript or jquery.

```
 <input  id="hm"  type="tel" />
```

**Javascript code :**

```
 <script>
    document.getElementById("hm").onkeyup=function(){
        var input=parseInt(this.value);
        if(input<0 || input>100)
        alert("Value should be between 0 - 100");
        return;
    }    
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can put min and max in an input type = number

try this

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
```

Comment: so you can only input 0-100 and step of 1 so you can increment it by only 1 step back and fort

Comment: this will not allow any input above 100  when you submit it to your database

Comment: it will not but when you submit it to your database it will not allow the above 100 input even thought users can put above 100